# ToMap operator output

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I do not get why studying RXJAva I found this output, I would expect, considering that `toMap` returns an HashMap, a different output with a Map with 5 key values, instead I get only a Map with 3 key values `{4=Beta, 5=Gamma, 7=Epsilon}`, why?

```
       Observable.just("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Quattro",
                "Epsilon")
                .toMap(String::length)//output {4=Beta, 5=Gamma, 7=Epsilon}
                .subscribe({it -> println(it) })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keys are the length of the strings; when multiple strings have the same length, the last one is inserted and replaces the previously inserted key/value pair. So `Gamma` removes `Alpha` and `Epsilon` removes `Quattro`.

Comment: I see Gamma removes Alpha because they have the same lenght, yes. thank you

Comment: need other 5 minutes to accept the answer:) because of SO